# HTTP POST request to send an image

Tags: ios, image, post, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to post an image to a webservice by means of an HTTP POST request.

The API doc says that image parameter should be the "binary file data for the image you would like analyzed - PNG, GIF, JPG only."

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"air.jpg"];
    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pictaculous.com/api/1.0/"]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:imgData];

    NSData *receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                 returningResponse:&response
                                                             error:&error];

    if(error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"web service error:%@",error);
    }
    else {
        if(receivedData !=nil) {
            NSError *Jerror = nil;
            NSDictionary* json =[NSJSONSerialization
                                 JSONObjectWithData:receivedData
                                 options:kNilOptions
                                 error:&Jerror];
            if(Jerror!=nil) {
                NSLog(@"json error:%@",Jerror);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that in the JSON response I always receive the error "You must provide an image" as if the format of the received image was not correct.

Isn't "UIImageJPEGRepresentation" the correct way to get binary data from an image ?

Is there any other way I can get the binary file data from my JPEG image ?

Thanks,
Corrado

Comment: convert ur uimage to base64 encoding and then pass the string to server,

Comment: always remember that u can't store the image in directly to the server, u need to follow the 3 steps , 1. ur image 2. confert UIImage to NSData 3. NSData to NSString and then finally pass the string to the server,

Comment: have u checked ur image is successfully stored in the server path

Comment: I replaced NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) with NSString *imgData = [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength] and modified the line [request setHTTPBody:[imgData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] but I always get the same error. Is this the correct implementation of your suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: actually u can't post the image to the server or fetch the image from server

Comment: u above coding is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simplify your code, you can use a simple NSURLConnection wrapper such as [STHTTPRequest](https://github.com/nst/STHTTPRequest).

```
STHTTPRequest *r = [STHTTPRequest requestWithURLString:@"http://pictaculous.com/api/1.0/"];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

[r addDataToUpload:data parameterName:@"image"];

r.completionBlock = ^(NSDictionary *headers, NSString *body) {
    NSLog(@"-- %@", body);
};

r.errorBlock = ^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"-- error: %@", error);
};

[r startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: I've tried also your code (I had to replace setFileToUpload with addFileToUpload and then the completion block completed correctly) but I still get the same error ("you must provide an image"). For sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't understand what ! The image is in the Resources so I changed the line to [r addFileToUpload:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"air" ofType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@""] parameterName:@"photo"]. Do you have any idea ? The API says I need to upload the binary data of the image ... should I do something on the image before uploading ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it works !! Thank you very much ... I was stuck on this problem ! Your code is the most simple I've seen and it works great. Thanks again.